# Php encode characters for telegram bot

Tags: php, html

Hy, i have this php code for telegram bot:

```
  header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId,  "text" => ''  .$temp.'&deg;C');
    $parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
    echo json_encode($parameters);
```

The problem is the encode of output, this will be & deg;C, i need °C.

If I use °, the code not work.

Comment: "the code not work" is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: @PeeHaa, if I use ° the bot not show any message. If I use & deg; the bot show for example:  5.9 & deg;

Comment: Did you try it with the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag?

Comment: yes but is the same result 
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId,  "text" => ''  .$temp.'&deg;C');
    $parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
    echo json_encode($parameters, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: No not with the html encoded value. With the actual `°` character

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this code:

```
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true,200");
    $parameters = array('chat_id' => $chatId,  "text" => ''  .$temp.'°C');
    $parameters["method"] = "sendMessage";
$parameters = array_map('utf8_encode', $parameters);
echo json_encode($parameters);
```

Comment: If `utf8_encode` works for you, that merely means that your original data was not encoded in UTF-8 but ISO-8859-1. Simply save your source code as UTF-8 in your text editor, use `"°C"` as is, and your original code will work.